# How can I force drill holes in Eagle

Tags: eaglecad

I have some routing like this;

[image]

I would like this pad/wire connection to print solid black with a small hole in the middle. After I etch with toner transfer, I'll need to see where to drill.

I can use drill-aid.ulp, but the resulting white donut's hole is obscured by the wire.

Surely this is not a unique problem. What's the trick?

Answer (score 3):

When exporting to postscript with the CAM tools, I select "fill pads". I then have to drill the hole by eye, but I get decent results.

When making two-sided boards, I fill the pads on the bottom and not on the top, then drill from the top.

Answer (score 2):

I have taken the file into photoshop and doctored all of the pads to have guide holes before printing.  Not elegant, but worked well.